# Print a value of a mongo documents inner key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document in the format:

```
{_id:ObjectId("541...009b"), name:"abc" data:{"F_001":123abc, "priority":"urgent", ...},... }
```

Wanted to write a common function to update a key {data.F_001:0}, otherwise all data will remain as it is:

```
updateExistingKey("user", {name:"abc"}, "data.F_001");
```

As I wasn't able to achieve that goal, I've tried to print the value, without any success:

```
function updateExistingKey(collection, query, keyname){
    db[collection].find(query).forEach(function(document) {
        print(document._id)        // prints ObjectId("541...009b")
        print(keyname)             // prints "data.F_001"
        print(document.data.F_001) // prints 123abc But
        print(document[keyname]);  // prints undefined rather than 123abc, why??
    });
}
```

Comment: what that [keyname] contains

Comment: @SatishShinde - "data.F_001", see the arguments updateExistingKey("user", {name:"abc"}, "data.F_001");

Comment: I read: _"[...] write a common function **to update** the data.userid"_ But: _"I'm not able **to print** the document key"_ What is the real need here? Update the document ? Or print the value of some arbitrary key ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux - Final need is to update the key. I was not able to update it, so tried printing it.

Comment: @trex That's why I though ;) Please note that, when trying to answer your question, I've noticed that you pass the _key name_ of the field to update as a parameter, but not the _value_ ? Is it hard-coded ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux - Yes, it is zero in this case. I will update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
>    print(document.data.F_001) // prints 123abc But
>    print(document[keyname]);  // prints undefined rather than 123abc, why??
>                                                                       ^^^
> ```

Embedded documents are *really* embedded (i.e.: nested). It is *not* a flat data structure with fields having a dot in them. So, the [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) might be seen as a *path* allowing you to access a field embedded in *nested* objects. Simply said, both are equivalent:

```
document.data.F_001
document["data"]["F_001"]
```

But is is not the same as

```
document["data.F_001"]
```

---

If you want to **update** one arbitrary field by its key name, your function prototype match very well the MongoDB [`update`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) function (with the notable exception the *value* is missing. I assume here it is hard coded). So a simple wrapper is all you need. Something *like* that:

```
function updateExistingKey(collection, query, keyname){
    updt = {};
    updt[keyname] = "SomeNewValue";

    db[collection].update(query,
                          {$set: updt},
                          {multi: true});
}
```

<sub>Untested: beware of the typos !</sub>

---

If you want to **retrieve** one arbitrary field, you might use the [`$project`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) operator of the aggregation framework to map your arbitrary field name to some known field in the output document:

```
function printExistingKey(collection, query, keyname){
    // XXX probably need some "keyname" validation here
    // ...

    db[collection].aggregate([
                      {$match: query },
                      {$project: { datafield: "$" + keyname }}
    ]).forEach(function(d) { print(d._id); print(d.datafield); });
}
```

<sub>Untested: beware of the typos !</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, It will work

```
function updateExistingKey(collection, query, keyname){
    db[collection].find(query).forEach(function(document) {
       print(document + "." + keyname);  
    });
}
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/

Comment: No it doesn't work. It prints like this `[object Object].data.F_001`